# Writing to an offset in Java?

Tags: file-io, bufferedreader, offset, filereader

Hmmm, so I already know how to read an offset in Java. My question is, how do you write to one?

Basically, I have a dat file like "test.dat"

In it, I have found a certain offset value, which I have been able to 'get'. I now have to be able to 'set' it, but am unsure how.

Answer (score 0):

To write into a random position or offset into a file, you can use a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), which internally uses a FileChannel, but provides a more easy to use interface.

Once you create a RandomAccessFile instance, you can positionate the file pointer (the offset from where to write/read) using the [seek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method. After that, all calls made to the object's methods will be using that offset as starting point, and will update the file pointer accordingly.